# Is R is an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Hello so I'm trying to make an exercise, but it makes no sense to me it goes as follows.

$Fun(X,Y)$ is the set of all functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$. We define a relation $R$ on $Fun(X,Y)$ by saying that $(f,g)\in R$ if and only if $$\{x \in X \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\}$$
is a finite set.

Prove that R is an equivalence relation?

But isn't that R is not an equivalence relation?

- Because for example if I would prove that this function is reflexive I would have to say that $f(x) \neq f(x)$.
- Hower I can say it is symmetric because if $f(x) \neq g(x)$ then surely $g(x) \neq f(x)$.
- And at last it is not transitive because if $f(x) \neq g(x)$ and $g(x) \neq h(x)$ then $f(x) \neq h(x) $ is not implied.

Is my thoughtprocess wrong or is it just the exercise?
If you can help me please share your wisdom

Thanks in advance

Comment: $(f,g) \in R$ if and only if... what?

Comment: No, to prove that $\langle f,f\rangle\in R$ you must show that $\{x\in X:f(x)\ne f(x)\}$ is finite — which it certainly is, since it’s empty!

Comment: $\{x \in X \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ @azif00

Comment: @TheCreator: No: that is not even a statement. $\langle f,g\rangle\in R$ if and only if that set **is finite**.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so for reflexivity you can say it holds becaus it's empty. For the function to be symmetric you can say if $f(x) \neq g(x) \rightarrow g(x) \neq f(x)$. But how can you say that it's transitive?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott could you give me an example of how such a set would look like because I can't get my head around about the reflevitiy and the transitivity because $f(x) \neq f(x)$ seems impossible, because even though it's empty. empty not equal to empty seems strange

Comment: @TheCreator: $f(x)\ne f(x)$ **is** impossible. That’s why the set $\{x\in X:f(x)\ne f(x)\}$ is empty: there cannot be any $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\ne f(x)$. And the empty set is certainly finite, so $\langle f,f\rangle\in R$. Suppose that $X=\Bbb N$, let $f(n)=n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, and let $g(n)=\max\{3,n\}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $f(3)=3=g(3)$, $f(4)=4=g(4)$, and so on, but $f(0)=0\ne 3=g(0)$, $f(1)=1\ne 3=g(1)$, and $f(2)=2\ne 3=g(2)$, so $$\{n\in\Bbb N:f(n)\ne g(n)\}=\{0,1,2\}\,.$$ This is a finite set, so $\langle f,g\rangle\in R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you’re not actually using the definition of $R$. For each ordered pair $\langle f,g\rangle$ of functions from $X$ to $Y$ you have to look at

$$\{x\in X:f(x)\ne g(x)\}\,,$$

the set of points in $X$ at which $f$ and $g$ disagree. For instance, if $X=Y=\Bbb N$, $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, and $g(n)=\max\{3,n\}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, then $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n\ge 3$, but $f(0)=0\ne 3=g(0)$, $f(1)=1\ne 3=g(1)$, and $f(2)=2\ne 3=g(2)$:

$$\{n\in\Bbb N:f(n)\ne g(n)\}=\{0,1,2\},,$$

because $f$ and $g$ differ at the points $0,1$, and $2$ and at no others. And this set is finite, so $\langle f,g\rangle\in R$.

Change the definition of $g$ by setting $g(n)=\min\{3,n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and you’d find that $f(n)=g(n)=n$ for $n\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, but $f(n)=n\ne 3=g(n)$ for $n>3$. Now

$$\{n\in\Bbb N:f(n)\ne g(n)\}=\{n\in\Bbb N:n\ge 4\}$$

is an infinite set, so $\langle f,g\rangle\notin R$.

It’s inconvenient to have to keep writing $\{x\in X:f(x)\ne g(x)\}$, so for $\langle f,g\rangle\in\operatorname{Fun}(X,Y)$ let

$$D(f,g)=\{x\in X:f(x)\ne g(x)\}\,;$$

this abbreviation will save a good bit of writing and reduce the visual clutter. By definition, then, $\langle f,g\rangle\in R$ if and only if $D(f,g)$ is finite.

Reflexivity should now be clear: for any $f:X\to Y$, $f(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in X$, so $D(f,f)=\varnothing$. $\varnothing$ is finite, so $\langle f,f\rangle\in R$, and $R$ is reflexive.

Symmetry is also easy. For any $f,g:X\to Y$, $D(f,g)=D(g,f)$. If $\langle f,g\rangle\in R$, then $D(f,g)$ is finite, so $D(g,f)=D(f,g)$ is finite, and therefore $\langle g,f\rangle\in R$.

It does take a little more work to prove that $R$ is transitive. Suppose that $\langle f,g\rangle,\langle g,h\rangle\in R$, so that $D(f,g)$ and $D(g,h)$ are finite subsets of $X$; we’d like to prove that $D(f,h)$ is also finite. This would certainly be true if we could show that $D(f,h)\subseteq D(f,g)\cup D(g,h)$, since the union of two finite sets is finite.

Suppose that $x\in X\setminus\big(D(f,g)\cup D(g,h)\big)$. Then $f(x)=g(x)$ (since $x\notin D(f,g)$), and $g(x)=h(x)$ (since $x\notin D(g,h)$), so $f(x)=h(x)$, and therefore $x\notin D(f,h)$, i.e., $x\in X\setminus D(f,h)$. In other words, we’ve shown that

$$X\setminus\big(D(f,g)\cup D(g,h)\big)\subseteq X\setminus D(f,h)$$

and hence that

$$D(f,h)\subseteq D(f,g)\cup D(g,h)\,,$$

as desired.